# Let $T =\{X\in P(\mathbb{Q}) | X\cup \mathbb{N} = \mathbb{Q} \}$ the cardinality of $T$ is $\aleph$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, cardinals

Let $T =\{X\in P(\mathbb{Q}) | X\cup \mathbb{N} = \mathbb{Q} \}$ the cardinality  of $T$ is $\aleph$ ? prove

attempt

we know that $X\in P(\mathbb{Q})$ so, $X\cup \mathbb{N} = \mathbb{Q}$ create an infinity numbers

Comment: What is $\aleph$?  $\aleph_0 = |\mathbb N|$ and $\aleph_1 = |\mathbb R| = 2^{\mathbb N}$ but what is $\aleph$?

Comment: @fleablood: As discussed in many many questions recently, it's the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: Is it?  I've always seen it refered to with the subindex $1$.  (And with the subindex $0$ it refers to $|\mathbb N|$.)  But those are a little outdated and I prefer either $2^{\mathbb N}$ or $|\mathbb R|$.

Comment: @fleablood $\aleph_1$ is not necessarily equal to $|\mathbb R|$. The continuum hypothesis says they’re equal, but that’s not provable or refutable from ZFC.

Comment: Hmmm.....  okay, I was taking $\aleph_1 = |\mathbb R|$ as a *definition* and the continuum hyptothesis as "There is no cardinality between $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$".  But if we define $\aleph_k$ and "the k-th cardinality past $|\mathbb N|$" the continuum hypothesis would be "$\aleph_1 =|\mathbb R|$". Which is why I don't like $\aleph$ notation.  I hadn't seen $\aleph$ used to mean the continuum before.  I've more frequently seen $\mathscr c$.

Answer (score 3):

It is clear from your definition that $T = \{ A \cup (\mathbb Q \setminus \mathbb N) \, | \, A \in P(\mathbb N) \}$. It can obviously be put in bijection with $P(\mathbb N)$ via the bijection $f: T \to P(\mathbb N)$ that sends $X$ to $X \cap \mathbb N$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer i don't see how i can prove this bijection holds( proving the function is injective and Surjective).

Comment: @Esty.R : The subsets $A$ and $\mathbb Q \setminus \mathbb N$ are disjoint by construction. So the map $X \mapsto X \cap \mathbb N$ just sends $A \cup (\mathbb Q \setminus \mathbb N)$ to $A$. The inverse map is just the opposite operation, namely sending a subset $A$ of $\mathbb N$ to $A \cup (\mathbb Q \setminus \mathbb N)$. You use the fact that $A$ and $\mathbb Q\setminus \mathbb N$ are disjoint to prove that this is a bijection.

Comment: That clarifies alot. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Esty.R : If my answer answers your question, give it a green check! That's the only reward I can get for my work! :D

Comment: I did not write the post , came across this question and thought is was interesting .So sadly i  can't  give it a green check. Although i did check both the comment and respond. Thanks.

Comment: @Esty.R : Oh sorry! I didn't look if you were the OP, I just assumed you were. Thanks for the upvote!

Answer (score 3):

It helps to get a "picture" of what is going on.

$T = \{X \in P(\mathbb Q)| ......\}$ means that $T$ is a set of subsets of $\mathbb Q$.  Our question is just which of the subsets and how many of subsets are in $T$.

If $X$ is one of the elements of $T$, the $X$ is subset of $T$ with the following property:  $X\cup \mathbb N = \mathbb Q$.

Now as $\mathbb N$ contains no non-integer rationals, doesn't contain $0$, and no negative rationals, $X$ must "provide" those in order for $X\cup \mathbb N = \mathbb Q$.  And if $L = \{q\in \mathbb Q| q\not \in \mathbb N\}=\mathbb Q\setminus L$ then $L\subset X$ for all $X\in T$.

So what *else* is in $X$?  That's the choice we have.  Every $X\in T$ is a subset of $\mathbb Q$ that contains $L$ as a subset.  And $X$ may or may not contain some natural numbers.  Lets define $X_a = \{n\in \mathbb N| n= X\}=$ the set of all natural numbers in $X$.

Then $X = L \cup X_a= $(the set of all rational numbers that are not in $\mathbb N$) $\cup$ (the set of all natural numbers in $X$).

Now we can describe each of the $X \in T$ by identifying which naturals it contains (everything else it has will be had by everty *other* $Y\in T$ so we can take those for granted).

So if we define $f(X) =X_a$ that is a mapping for $X \in T$ to $X_a$ which is in $P(\mathbb N)$ as it is subset of $\mathbb N$.  So $f: T\to P(\mathbb N)$.

And further more $f$ is a bijection.  It's injective because for any two different $X,Y\in T$ they both will contain all the non-naturals so the only thing that distinguishes them are the natural numbers they contain.  In other words, $X \ne Y$ if and only if $X_a \ne Y_a$.

And $f$ is surjective.  For any $K \subset N$ then the set $L \cup K$ will one of the subsets in $T$.

So $f:T\to P(\mathbb N)$ is a bijection.

So $|T| = |P(\mathbb N)|$.

.....

Now I think in you class you have probably had it proven that $|P(\mathbb N)| = 2^{\mathbb N} = |\mathbb R| \ne  |\mathbb N|$.

so $T =  |\mathbb R| \ne  |\mathbb N|$.